# Qeum kvm virtual host (windows xp sp3) can't see HDD

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm trying to install windows xp sp3 on qemu kvm
Here is virtualhost configuration:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>windowsxp3</name>
  <uuid>f5b8c05b-9c7a-3211-49b9-2bd635f7e2ab</uuid>
  <memory>2096576</memory>
  <currentMemory>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/windowsxp3.img"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x04" function="0x0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/boot/ru-windows-xp-sp3.iso"/>
      <target dev="hdc" bus="ide"/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="1" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <mac address="00:00:A3:B0:56:12"/>
    </interface>
    <controller type="ide" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5901' autoport="no" listen='0.0.0.0'/>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </console>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I've created a proper .img file (qcow2) and specified in config disk driver type qcow2 and raw, but no affect. Windows installer can't locate any hdd...

Comment: XP is probably too old for that. And it shouldn't be used now for obvious reasons.

Comment: i've read miscelaneous topics in internet that even xp sp2 works with kvm, the other thing is that's unstable enough...

Comment: XP is unsupported since 2014. That's the obvious reason for NOT using it.